# Extract a zip file using php in apache server not working

Tags: php, apache, unzip, permission-denied

I want to extract a zip file using php in apache server. But i got an error on this.
This is my code.

```
 $enviornment = "zip -P test -r /var/www/test/test.zip /var/www/test/output/";

  exec($enviornment, $output, $return);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($output);
```

This is Error message.

```
  [0] => zip I/O error: Permission denied
  [1] => zip error: Could not create output file (/var/www/test/test.zip)
```

I already place right permission in /var/www/test/output/ folder.

Comment: Make sure all folders have proper write permissions.

Comment: Can you update your question and list `ls` your rights from `/var/www/test`.

Comment: _"I already place right permission in /var/www/test/output/ folder."_: I don't trust you :). So, open a terminal and `ls /var/www/test` and also `ls /var/www/test/output` to know exactly which rights are set.

Comment: i already double checked. I give right permission to apache. I can't list here bcoz there is some technical problem for me.

Comment: Yes but depending on your OS, permission should be, for instance, `www-data`. But anyway, if for you it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use zip, but you need to use unzip instead - what you are doing is **creating** archive from /var/www/test/output/, check man page for details:

> The basic command format is
>
> ```
>           zip options archive inpath inpath ...
> ```
>
> where archive is a new or existing zip archive and inpath is a directory or file path optionally including wildcards.  When given the
>   name of an existing zip  archive,  zip  will  replace  identically
>          named  entries  in  the  zip  archive (matching the relative names as stored in the archive) or add entries for new names.  For
>   example, if foo.zip exists and contains foo/file1 and foo/file2, and
>   the
>          directory foo contains the files foo/file1 and foo/file3, then:
>
> ```
>           zip -r foo.zip foo
>
>    or more concisely
>
>           zip -r foo foo
> ```
>
> will replace foo/file1 in foo.zip and add foo/file3 to foo.zip.  After this, foo.zip contains foo/file1, foo/file2, and foo/file3, with
>   foo/file2 unchanged from before.

Try unzip instead, or ZIP extensions for PHP http://php.net/manual/en/intro.zip.php